# Unblocking adb logcat in batch file

Tags: android, adb

i want to have batch file for adb logging , my batch file goes like this

```
adb root
adb remount
adb shell cd /data/log/

adb shell logcat –v time >log_0.txt 
adb shell logcat –v time –b radio >log_radio_0.txt &

adb pull /data/log/
```

the first logcat is blocking .. so the next logcat does not execute..
Please suggest how to unblock logcat here.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Try this...

```
adb shell logcat -d -v time >log_0.txt
```